# How to keep a package with unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management

(this is Linux Mint 14, but I think it's still relevant here)

I've installed gnapi package from deb file. It had one dependency which wasn't met (libnautilus-extension1), but I forced installation and everything works fine.

But now when I want to install skype deb (or just launch synaptic), it displays message that system is broken.
Trying to fix it the reccomended way:

> sudo apt-get install -f

would result in removing gnapi, which is working fine (and I need it).

How can I fix the broken state, but keep the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the *equivs* package? (inherited from debian)